# TypeScript package with multiple entry points

Tags: typescript, node-modules, es6-modules, commonjs

The standard way to expose node package modules is to list them in the index.ts, like so:

```js
export * from './module1';
export * from './module2';
```

However, this loads the content of both modules immediately. I want to have a module that is not exported in the index.ts file, as it requires some optional dependencies to be installed.

I followed this guide: https://blog.mozilla.org/data/2021/04/07/this-week-in-glean-publishing-glean-js/

My package.json:

```json
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/es/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/index.js"
    },
    "./module2": {
      "import": "./dist/es/module2.js",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/module2.js"
    }
  },
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      ".": [
        "./dist/types/index.d.ts"
      ],
      "./module2": [
        "./dist/types/module2.d.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
// fallback for older Node versions:
  "module": "dist/es/index.js",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
```

After I build the project (with `tsc`, separately for CJS and ESM) the output dir structure looks like this:

```
- dist
  - cjs
    - index.js
    - module2.js
  - es
    - index.js
    - module2.js
  - types
    - index.d.ts
    - module2.d.ts
```

However, when I publish this package and install it in the client project, module2 does not work.

```js
import {sayHello} from 'ts-exports-test';
import {sayGoodbye} from 'ts-exports-test/module2';

console.log(sayHello());
console.log(sayGoodbye());
```

I run it with `ts-node` and I'm getting the error:

```
src/index.ts:2:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ts-exports-test/module2' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

---

Note: with clients using TS 4.5 the types paths can be declared in "exports" section, making the "typesVersions" hack unnecessary. But this is for the future.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, but it's working for me. Could you check this repo and check if there is any difference with your configuration https://github.com/diedu89/ts-export-import-test

Comment: Thanks for trying to reproduce it. However, in your example, the `ts-exports-test/module2` import in the client resolves to `module2.ts` file in the package main dir, not to `dist/types/module2.d.ts` (according to WebStorm). If you remove the source files from the output package by adding `"files": ["dist"]` to package.json or if you move the source files to `src` directory, it won't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It works if you define the paths in typesVersions like this:

```
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "*": [
        "dist/types/index.d.ts"
      ],
      "module2": [
        "dist/types/module2.d.ts"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Not sure what convention does it follows, but it looks like paths like `.` or `./` are not valid.

You can check the repo https://github.com/diedu89/ts-export-import-test

Answer (score 11):

**2022, TypeScript 4.9 and beyond**

[`exports` is prioritized over `typesVersions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#exports-is-prioritized-over-typesversions)

Previously, TypeScript incorrectly prioritized the `typesVersions` field over the `exports` field when resolving through a `package.json` under `--moduleResolution node16`. If this change impacts your library, you may need to add `types@` version selectors in your `package.json`’s `exports` field. The proper way to do this is using `exports` field now -

```json
{
      "type": "module",
      "exports": {
          ".": {
              "import": "./dist/es/index.js",
              "require": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
              "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts"  ✅
          },
          "module2" {
              "import": "./dist/es/module2.js",
              "require": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
              "types": "./dist/types/module2.ts"  ✅
          }
      }
  }
```